# how to achieve commit and rollback using @Transaction using jdbi and dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I tried to get a proper example of how to handle @transaction in JDBI and Dropwizard. Mycode is looking like this

```
DAO:

public abstract class DoStuff{
@SqlQuery("select qyery")
public abstract List<Confirmchemtemp> getAllconfirm(parameters);

@GetGeneratedKeys
@SqlUpdate("insert query")
protected abstract int insert(parameters);  

@GetGeneratedKeys
@SqlUpdate("insert query")
protected abstract int insertTrans(parameters); 

@GetGeneratedKeys
@SqlUpdate("insert query")
protected abstract int insertTransdet(parameters);

@SqlUpdate("update query")
protected abstract int update(parameters);

@Transaction
public String doStuff(){
    List<Confirmchemtemp> list = getAllconfirm();
    insert(parameters);
    insertTrans(parameters);
    insertTransdet(parameters);
    update(parameters); 
 }
 }



 RESOURCES:

 @Path("/getconfirm")
 @POST
 public String doStuff(){       
  return ddd.doStuff();
  }
```

but rollback is not happening. Can anyone tell me what wrong I did in my code??? and am using config.yml for database configuration.

Comment: Why should a rollback happen? If nothing inside the transaction fails the transaction is committed, not rolled back.

Comment: Rollback happens when exceptions are thrown in a transactional method.

Comment: Hi @intentionallyleftblank, how to do a rollback the full process when the update condition fails.

Comment: Hi @NiVeR , if an update is failed I want to Rollback the process[if any update is not happening]. I tried but I didn't get it.

Comment: The `@Transaction` will take care of rolling back if an exception is thrown.

Comment: can I raise exception manually based on the condition for update statement such as the minimum one-row need to be updated or else I have to rollback entire process @intentionallyleftblan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to throw a `org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.TransactionException`. For example, if you want to check that `insert` returned an integer different from 0, you could do this:

```
@Transaction
public String doStuff() {
    List<Confirmchemtemp> list = getAllconfirm();
    int key = insert(parameters);
    if (key == 0) {
        throw new TransactionException("nothing inserted");
    }
    insertTrans(parameters);
    insertTransdet(parameters);
    update(parameters); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you..!!  @intentionallyleftblank